# Regular graph and connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any property defining that a regular graph is connected if the graph is k-connected and k is > something?

I'm looking to prove that a graph with 2n vertex, each with grade n is connected.

Answer (score 1):

If a graph has $2k-1$ vertices, and is $k$ regular, it has to be connected.

How to prove ? try by contradiction....

Answer (score 1):

You must have an upper bound on the number of vertices to be sure that the graph is connected. Because if you have a $k$-regular graph, it's always possible to create two disjoint copies of this graph (this graph will still be $k$-regular) but it will not be connected.